# Insert local data into SQL Server temp table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ms-access, odbc, ms-access-2007

I have a few stored procedures that use temporary tables to read a list of IDs to perform updates on. I also have a local query with a list of IDs that I'd like to pass to one of those stored procedures. Is there any way to do something like this?

```
INSERT INTO #MyBackendTempTable
SELECT ID
FROM MyLocalQuery
```

I suppose I could do this by looping through recordsets in VBA, which I'll do if I have to, but it would be much nicer to have a set-wise way of doing this. I know Access can do passthrough queries, but to the best of my knowledge, they can only act on objects on the server. Is there some simple method for this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: In SQL Server 2008 you could use TVPs. Why are you still using 2005?

Comment: @Aaron: Maybe because many large corps move real sloooow. Corporation I worked for last year was in processs of moving from 2000 to 2005!

Comment: @AaronBertrand I'd love to, and I'm working on it with the powers that be. But for now, I have to work with what I've got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if the query is really that simple, and you just have a set of IDs (one column), you could build a comma-separated list in the front end, then pass it to a stored procedure in the back end and split it using your favorite split mechanism ([I have a favorite](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)). Your stored procedure would be (assuming the #temp table was created previously in the same scope):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.whatever
  @IDList VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT #MyBackendTempTable(ID) SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split(@IDList);
END
GO
```

And in the front end you would build a comma-separated list to pass to that one parameter.

Or you can use a permanent table with some key based on spid, application instance, what have you - assuming that you can uniquely identify each user. Then you would do:

```
INSERT dbo.MyBackEndPermanentTable(Session, ID)
  SELECT 'SessionSomething', ID
  FROM MyLocalQuery;
```

Comment: Nice. I like the second option a lot. I should have thought of it myself, considering that I already use a couple of staging tables in my backend. Thanks!